# Fast way to search for particular string (or byte array) in another process memory in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, search, readprocessmemory

Please post a working source code example (or link) of how to search string in another process memory and getting offset of match if found. The similar way its done in game cheating utils which search for values in game memory using ReadProcessMemory.

Comment: You forgot to say "PLEASE SEND ME THE SOURCE CODES ASAP AS IT IS URGENT"

Comment: Wow, this site is truely full of low life asses.

Comment: For all those still searching, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7541052/303290 might be of some help, although it might not be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [Memory Mapped Files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) as a way to share memory between separate processes.  You'll need to use Win32 P/Invokes to implement this in C#, see this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/globalcache.aspx) link for an example that you may be able to adapt.