# C#: Search a byte[] array in another process's memory

Tags: c#, memory, process

How is it possible to search for a byte[] array in the memory of another process and then get the address at the place where the byte[] array is located?

I want to write a byte array into the memory of another process(WriteProcessMemory()).One of the parameters of that call is uint Address.Well I want to get the address by searching a byte array into the process.

For example I search for {0xEB ,0x20,0x68,0x21,0x27,0x65, ??, 0x21,0x64,0xA1}

We assume that this array is placed only at one place in the memory of the process I'd like to write memory to.

To get that address,I have to search for that byte array.

Is it possible to be done in C#?

**EDIT:** **This is for native applications,NOT .NET. No need to downvote my question,there are components for C++ that do this,I just want to do it in C#.**

Thanks for understanding!

Comment: I don't want to use external C++ dll ,because it requires Runtime and I'd like to work with memory in NET aswell.

Comment: John: there is no runtime you need for a native application that is not included with Windows, and you will have to work with raw memory anyway.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Is it possible to be done in C#?

Yes. But very hard. It is hard from a native application where there is no impedance mismatched with the unmanaged view of processes and their memory maps you will need to use.

Considerations:

- You will need permission to open the process to get a handle.
- While the virtual memory space of a 32bit process is from two to four GB in size (depending on host OS and /3GB switch), much of this address range will not be allocated, and reading it will cause a page fault. You really need to find out what pages are allocated and for what to avoid lots of invalid page accesses.

Suggestions:

- Do you really really need to do this? Seriously this will be hard.
- Consider doing a native application, this will avoid working across the native/managed fence (this could include a native library with a managed driver application).
- Do you really need to do this?
- Consider doing the work inside the target process. This will require some cleverness (documented) to inject a thread, but should then be much faster.
- Start by reading up on Windows how process memory works (start with Windows Internals and (can't recall its name in the latest edition) Jeffrey Richter's book on Win32 application development.
- Do you really need to do this? There must be something simpler... could you automated a debugger?

Comment: I can get the address in the debugger,the problem is that the application I'm doing this on is commercial and is being updated once a week.I guess I have to do this.

Comment: @John: In that case, both VS and windbg have extensibility models (VS is .NET) which should avoid all the hard work.

Comment: The VS extensibility model is covered on MSDN (under Visual Studio ... SDK). Not sure where to start with WinDBG off hand.

Answer (score 17):

Is it possible to be done in C#?
Everithing is possible in c#(or any other languge), u just need to fiind how;

Hard coding here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
          static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
          IntPtr hProcess,
          IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
          [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
          int dwSize,
          out int lpNumberOfBytesRead
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
        if (procs.Length <= 0)  //proces not found
            return; //can replace with exit nag(message)+exit;
        IntPtr p = OpenProcess(0x10 | 0x20, true, procs[0].Id); //0x10-read 0x20-write

        uint PTR = 0x0; //begin of memory
        byte[] bit2search1 = {0xEB ,0x20,0x68,0x21,0x27,0x65}; //your bit array until ??
        int k = 1;  //numer of missing array (??)
        byte[] bit2search2 = {0x21,0x64,0xA1};//your bit array after ??
        byte[] buff = new byte[bit2search1.Length+1+bit2search2.Length];    //your array lenght;
        int bytesReaded;
        bool finded = false;

        while (PTR != 0xFF000000)   //end of memory // u can specify to read less if u know he does not fill it all
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(p, (IntPtr)PTR, buff, buff.Length, out bytesReaded);
            if (SpecialByteCompare(buff, bit2search1,bit2search2,k))
            {
                //do your stuff
                finded = true;
                break;
            }
            PTR += 0x1;
        }
        if (!finded)
            Console.WriteLine("sry no byte array found");
    }

    private static bool SpecialByteCompare(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, byte[] b3, int k)  //readed memory, first byte array, second byte array, number of missing byte's
    {
        if (b1.Length != (b2.Length + k + b3.Length))
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < b2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (b1[i] != b2[i])
                return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b3.Length; i++)
        {
            if (b1[b2.Length + k + i] != b3[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Danie - The example might help others - nice

Comment: +1 For actually responding to the question without trying to stay fancy and being moral.

Comment: Contrary to this answer, what is being asked for is *not* possible, neither from C# nor an unmanaged language. As written, this code is missing 2 parts, one that's aesthetic ([VirtualQueryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907.aspx) to get a map of used memory), and one that's absolutely vital (suspending all threads). You cannot safely do the latter, as the threads would need to be in a 'safe' state, prior to suspending them. The OS provides no support to determine this, neither does the runtime. This really just implements a TOCTTOU race.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you could use the [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(VS.85).aspx) Windows API call. There's even a [premade P/Invoke signature](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadProcessMemory.html) for it so you don't need to bother with manually crafting it. You page through the memory of the process, search through it for your pattern and you're done.

Comment: I need to specify the address where I have to call that(one of its parameters is address).Well my question is:How to get the address by searching into the memory.I thought searching through the whole image,but that will take much time.

Comment: Supposing that you're doing that in a 32-bit environment, it makes sense to use 4096-bytes pages for your lookup, that's 1048576 total. ReadProcessMemory returns false if the address is not accessible which speeds up the loop considerably. I don't think it would take a lot of time to finish especially since it's very unlikely that your pattern will be over 1GB. And you don't really have any other choice either.

Comment: @John: you will need to use memory APIs to only read memory that is readable (checkout VMMap.exe with showing free memory enabled... most of the virtual memory map is unused).

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use these APIs:

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32.Dll")]
    public static extern uint VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr ProcessHandle, uint Address, ref MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION MemInfo, int MemInfoLength);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.Dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr ProcessHandle, uint Address, byte[] Buffer, uint Size, ref uint BytesRead);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.Dll")]
    public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr ProcessHandle, uint Address, byte[] Buffer, uint Size, ref uint BytesRead);
```

[pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/VirtualQueryEx.html) is a great resource for Windows API calls.  I wrote a trainer for GTA: Vice City that uses these calls if you want to check out the [code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vicecheat/files/vicecheat/ViceCheat%200.9/) on sourceforge.  The code isn't pretty, it was a long time ago and I just threw it together, but there are helper classes for enumerating memory regions for a process and searching for certain bytes or strings.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you find the right way:

```
private static int GetMemoryAddressOfString(byte[] searchedBytes, Process p)
{
    //List<int> addrList = new List<int>();
    int addr = 0;
    int speed = 1024*64;
    for (int j = 0x400000; j < 0x7FFFFFFF; j+= speed)
    {
        ManagedWinapi.ProcessMemoryChunk mem = new ProcessMemoryChunk(p, (IntPtr)j, speed + searchedBytes.Length);

        byte[] bigMem = mem.Read();

        for (int k = 0; k < bigMem.Length - searchedBytes.Length; k++)
        {
            bool found = true;
            for (int l = 0; l < searchedBytes.Length; l++)
            {
                if(bigMem[k+l] != searchedBytes[l])
                {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found)
            {
                addr = k+j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (addr != 0)
        {
            //addrList.Add(addr);
            //addr = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    //return addrList;
    return addr;
}
```

Comment: I like this method better than searching the pattern using ReadProcessMemory(). However, this has problem while searching for pattern in non-writable memory region.