# c# search in another process's memory - sudden lockout

Tags: c#, memory, process

I need to keep track of another program's memory, constantly looking for a sequence of bytes to appear in there, and when they do, i need to remember their location so i later know where to write to.

I used the following post to learn how to look for byte[] in another process's memory:
[C#: Search a byte[] array in another process's memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781716/c-search-a-byte-array-in-another-processs-memory)

My program is very simple: It launches process (using Process.Start), and then repeatedly runs function from the linked thread's one of the answers:

```
private static  int GetMemoryAddressOfString(byte[] searchedBytes)
    {
        IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.VMOperation | ProcessAccessFlags.VMRead | ProcessAccessFlags.VMWrite, false, Program.ArtemisProcess.Id);
        if (hProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        int addr = 0;
        int speed = 1024 * 64;
        for (int j = 0x00400000; j < 0x11000000; j += speed)
        {
            byte[] bigMem = new byte[speed + searchedBytes.Length];

            IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
            ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (IntPtr)j, bigMem, new UIntPtr((uint)(speed + searchedBytes.Length)), unmanagedPointer);
            int result = Marshal.ReadInt32(unmanagedPointer);
            Marshal.DestroyStructure(unmanagedPointer, typeof(int));

            for (int k = 0; k < bigMem.Length - searchedBytes.Length; k++)
            {
                bool found = true;
                for (int l = 0; l < searchedBytes.Length; l++)
                {
                    if (bigMem[k + l] != searchedBytes[l])
                    {
                        found = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found)
                {
                    addr = k + j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (addr != 0)
                break;
        }
        return addr;
    }
```

where ArtemisProcess is the Process i ran with .Start()

Most of the times, it works fine. As soon as i do the action in the watched process that puts the searched sequence of bytes to the memory, the next search finds it. However, sometimes, it wont.

I was wondering if i'm right and used Cheat Engine to be sure that the searched data IS there.

Then i added the part where i create an unmanaged pointer to know how many bytes there were read - and thats when i found out that exactly the place in the memory where the searched bytes appear (that Cheat Engine correctly identifies) returns 0! It wont let me read memory there. This "lockout" happens for about a minute or two, and only then it allows me to read the memory (just out of sudden, the next attempt to read the memory at that location is a success and the sequence of bytes is found all right).

Now, i read on the msdn that "he function fails if the requested read operation crosses into an area of the process that is inaccessible" but how do i know which part of the process memory is accessible and which isnt?

Why is Cheat Engine able to read that memory, and my program isnt?

Why does it suddenly allow me to read the process memory again?

I am at a loss here...

Comment: Shouldn't your `unmanagedPointer` in your call to `ReadProcessMemory` be a `ref UInt32`?

Comment: I am not familliar with how refs relate to pointers, so i decided to use a code i found on the webs. I could just do IntPtr result and then pass ref result to the dll call?