# Get Open Process Windows Textbox with C#

Tags: c#, process

I need to find open process or application textbox and change its value. But i wanna do it with c# way. If anyone knows could you please share with me? Or do i have to use c++ and how?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Do you want to find the window? or the actual process in memory? By change its value do you mean a window you have control over from your application?

Comment: i am trying to find some.exe and its open windows also textboxes in its. and i will actually have to give string. i guess i need to change memory value. but i have no idea how to.

Comment: Is the process you're opening an application YOU wrote? If so, you can use IPC libraries to communicate with that process.

Comment: no its not my programme.its written with delphi. my users trying to enter save path with manually. and i have to save their day.

Answer (score 3):

Like another said, UIAutomation is the way to go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107.aspx

The following code will open Notepad.exe, open its File dialog, then type in some text into the file name field.

```
        Process notepad = Process.Start("notepad");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        SendKeys.SendWait("^o"); //ctrl+o to open the File Dialog

        var notepadTextBox = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, 
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "1148"));

        object valuePattern = null;

        if (notepadTextBox.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out valuePattern))
        {
            ((ValuePattern)valuePattern).SetValue("THERE YOU GO"); // this text will be entered in the textbox
        }
        else 
        {
            //ERROR
        }
```

So this is really a combination of sending keystrokes to control the UI (bring up the File Open dialog) & UIAutomation, but you could change it to drive the Menu like a user would if you need to.

Also you might be wondering where the magic string "1148" comes from - that is the "Automation Id" of the file name entry field in Notepad. I used inspect.exe (included in the Windows SDK) to find the automation Id, you will need that for your application to see its AutomationIds, if it has any.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is if the application is out of your control in terms of using libraries and wrappers:

`Process[] Procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("NameofProcess");`

that will give you the process in question. Now this is where it will get tricky and depend upon what exactly you need to do.

You would eventually need to find where the strings are stored in memory, you could use a memory profiler to do this or something like CheatEngine to find the values, not going to get into what you use CheatEngine for or how you use it, but it is just a simple way of finding memory locations.

You could then read/write to the memory locations using something like this:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
    public static byte[] ReadMem(IntPtr MemAddy, uint bytestoread, Process Proc)
    {
        //
        //Create new Memory buffer and pointer to that buffer
        //
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytestoread];
        IntPtr bufferptr;
        //
        //Read Process Memory and output to buffer
        //
        ReadProcessMemory(Proc.Handle, MemAddy, buffer, bytestoread, out bufferptr);
        //
        //Return the buffer
        //
        return buffer;
    }

    public static bool WriteMem(IntPtr MemAddy, byte[] buffer, Process Proc)
    {
        int NumWriten;
        WriteProcessMemory(Proc.Handle, MemAddy, buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, out NumWriten);
        if (NumWriten != buffer.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
```

These two functions would allow you to read and write to some arbitrary processes memory locations.

if you want the window in question you could use:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Like So:

```
    IntPtr HWND = FindWindow(null, "WinName");
```

Which will give you the handle to the window in question.

Another way to do this would be to find the window and then pass some events to it, like bring the window to focus and then tab through the text boxes programmatically. However without more information about what exactly you are trying to do I am not sure what else to say here.

Comment: Umm I guess firstly what is it you want explained? which tactic?

Comment: emm. i just need to inject my folder path to opened someprogramme.exe textbox. thats it. i will decide which folder will it be.my purpose of this application is easy. just find the textbox which specific programme opened. lets say its notepad++ and i wanna write something on its new document.thats it.

Comment: Well if that is the case I would have to say go with the answer posted by @canhazbits, unless you cannot use the UIAutomation idea, in which case you will need to use the above and find the specific memory locations of where the text boxes save the strings, which will be very different depending on the application. It is just a matter of searching and finding the right location. You can do this with a variety of tools just google process memory search. You can take a look at this for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781716/c-search-a-byte-array-in-another-processs-memory

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are looking for is [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). It will let you see the other program's controls and send text to those controls. I have done this in the past where I had to export data from a corrupted database and I had to click OK on a dialog every time it hit a corrupted record.

The topic is too complex to go in to depth on how to do it in the space of a SO answer, but [here is a tutorial I found on CodePlex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141842/Automate-your-UI-using-Microsoft-Automation-Framew) that goes over how to do it.

There are also 3rd party wrapper libraries to make it easier to do. My personal favorite is [White](http://teststack.github.io/White/).